# How to change column title dynamically in Kendo UI TreeList?

Tags: jquery, .net, asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui, kendo-treelist

I need to change the column header/title according to the data. is there any way to achieve this functionality.

Currently the title is hard coded as follows:

```
        $("#grid").kendoTreeList({
            dataSource: drillDownDataSource,
            resizable: true,
            autoBind: true,
            columns: [
                { field: "Title", title: " ", width: "297px" },
                { field: "EndingBalance",  title: "EndingBalance",  template: "#: FormatNumberToEn(EndingBalance) #" },
                { field: "EndingBalance1", title: "EndingBalance1", template: "#: FormatNumberToEn(EndingBalance1) #" },
                { field: "EndingBalance2", title: "EndingBalance2", template: "#: FormatNumberToEn(EndingBalance2) #" },
                { field: "EndingBalance3", title: "EndingBalance3", template: "#: FormatNumberToEn(EndingBalance3) #" },
                { field: "EndingBalance4", title: "EndingBalance4", template: "#: FormatNumberToEn(EndingBalance4) #" }
            ],
            dataBound: function (e) {
                $('#grid').show();
                $('#GridPanelLoading').hide();
            },
```

Comment: you can assign a variable which has the required title string, Also can you give me an example of what title to set on what kind of data

Comment: thanks for the reply man !!! it worked

Answer (score 4, accepted):

see [Demo](http://dojo.telerik.com/eNuPe)

1- use [headerTemplate](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/ui/treelist#configuration-columns.headerTemplate)

```
$("#treelist").kendoTreeList({
        columns: [ {
            field: "name",
            headerTemplate: '#= getHeader() #'
        }],
...
```

2- or change column header by jQuery

```
$("#treelist thead [data-field=name]").html("New Title")
```

Comment: this doesn't change the header in the exported excel file. (number 2)